# How to get and use type inferred from generic

Tags: generics, types, enumerable, crystal-lang

In the following example, I suppose I have to deal with an Enumerable type of some data structures, filled by litterals :

```
module TestGenerics
  class Foo(T)
    include Enumerable(T)

    def initialize(@data : T)
      typeof(@data)
      typeof(@data.first)
    end
  end
  Foo.new(1..3)
  Foo.new([1, 'A', 3.14])
  Foo.new([[1, 'A', 3.14], [2, 'Z', 9.99]])
  Foo.new({"A" => [1, 'A', 3.14], "B" => [2, 'Z', 9.99]})
end
```

For each instanciation of the Foo class, typeof(@data) gives :

1. Range(Int32, Int32)
2. Array(Char | Float64 | Int32)
3. Array(Array(Char | Float64 | Int32))
4. Hash(String, Array(Char | Float64 | Int32))

and typeof(@data.first) gives :

1. Int32
2. (Char | Float64 | Int32)
3. Array(Char | Float64 | Int32)
4. Tuple(String, Array(Char | Float64 | Int32))

That's good, but now, my problem is : how can I use any of these inferred types by the Crystal Compiler in other part of my code ? Or is it at all impossible ?!

Thanks

[EDIT]
My question originates from my project to adapt a personal application written in Ruby to the Crystal language (which I am discovering). This application uses the Ruby Gem Tabulo (https://github.com/matt-harvey/tabulo), so I am trying to also adapt this Gem to the Crystal language.

This Ruby Gem aims at formatting data tables (in fact, any type of enumerable data structure), by defining colums to be displayed. This is done by a function "add_column", which has among its parameters various formatting attributes, and, more important, a block to access the underlying data, at the "row" level (whose type is given by typeof(@data.first) in the example code). I made the adaptation by taking a specific type of data : Array(Array(Float64)). It works, and my goal now is to make this adaptation generic, likely to take any kind of Enumerable data input, as shown in the example code above.

So, as far as my (poor) skills allow me to understand how Crystal works in this case, I need to use the data type defined by the input data structure.

Sorry if this explanation is a bit lacking of details, but the Tabulo Gem logic is fairly complex, and pretty difficult to summarize in a few words.
Thanks for your help, anyway.

Comment: What do you want to do with those types? Otherwise it's a bit hard to give you a reply...

Comment: Please, see original message Edit

Answer (score 0):

So I'm still having a hard time understanding what you're trying to do. If you want to branch depending on the type, you can use a `case`.

```
var = 5
var = 5..10 if Random.rand > 0.5
case var
when Int32
  puts "int inside here"
when Range(Int32, Int32)
  puts "range inside here"
end
```

Maybe you are looking for [Enumerable](https://crystal-lang.org/api/latest/Enumerable.html), which gives a set of methods that can be used for all of the different types?

```
enumerable = [1,5,6]
enumerable = {2,7,8} if Random.rand > 0.5
# Draw top of table
# #each is defined from Enumerable, so is available to both Array and Tuple
enumerable.each do |val|
  puts "|#{val}|"
end
# Draw end of table
```